# Edit JavaFX CSS at runtime

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a CSS stylesheet for a JavaFX 8 application.

I'm repeating these steps several times:

1. Edit the CSS
2. Run the application and see the changes
3. Stop the application

I found this approach very time-consuming and looking for something smarter.

**Is it possibile to edit the CSS of my JavaFX application while running and see the result in real-time?**

I'm looking for something like the [Inspect tool of Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles).

This can be *partially* reached by using [Oracle Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html). In fact I can load a CSS file and run the preview. Any change to the CSS file is correctly shown in the preview without the need to restart.

Unfortunately that's just a preview: many components are empty/uninitialized. Sure this is anyway very helpful, but many refinements require the real application running.

Comment: the closest thing I found is https://code.google.com/p/fx-scene-tool/

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change using getStylesheets() / setStyle() etc.

In the example below I had to use a temp file as I am changing the CSS of the scene, when using into single components this is not necessary as you can change directly in the components.

[image]

You may download this [example on gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/ed52b2951a69f0c27205).

**Test.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("doc.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
        CSSController myController = loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        myController.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**CSSController.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class CSSController implements Initializable{
    private Scene scene;
    @FXML TextArea cssContent;
    @FXML Button defineCSSButton;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        defineCSSButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String css = cssContent.getText();
                try{
                    File temp = new File("tempfile.css"); 
                    temp.delete();
                    temp.createNewFile();
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
                    bw.write(css);
                    bw.close();
                    String url = "tempfile.css";
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(temp.toURI().toString());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    public void setScene(Scene scene) { this.scene = scene; }
}
```

**doc.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
    prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CSSController">
    <children>
        <TextArea fx:id="cssContent" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="26.0"
            prefHeight="292.0" prefWidth="319.0" />
        <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Define your CSS here:" />
        <Button fx:id="defineCSSButton" layoutX="14.1875" layoutY="333.5"
            mnemonicParsing="false" text="Define CSS" />
        <Line endY="400.0" layoutX="332.0" />
        <Label layoutX="418.0" layoutY="15.0" text="Components:" />
        <ChoiceBox layoutX="343.0" layoutY="48.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
        <ColorPicker layoutX="343.3759765625" layoutY="86.0" />
        <CheckBox layoutX="347.6650390625" layoutY="123.0"
            mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
        <MenuButton layoutX="343.37109375" layoutY="159.5"
            mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
            <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action" />
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action" />
                <CheckMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action" />
            </items>
        </MenuButton>
        <ProgressIndicator layoutX="347.9091796875" layoutY="200.01953125"
            progress="0.0" />
        <Slider layoutX="410.0" layoutY="213.01953125" />
        <ToggleButton layoutX="348.7421875" layoutY="254.0"
            mnemonicParsing="false" text="ToggleButton" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Css in the screenshot:

```css
.label{
-fx-font: 15px "System Bold";
-fx-text-fill: #FF0000;
}

.button{
    -fx-background-color:
        #c3c4c4,
        linear-gradient(#d6d6d6 50%, white 100%),
        radial-gradient(center 50% -40%, radius 200%, #e6e6e6 45%, rgba(230,230,230,0) 50%);
    -fx-background-radius: 30;
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,1;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 3, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
```